# How to paste using the keys command in nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

How can I paste in nightwatch? I tried this command:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.COMMAND, browser.Keys.v])
```

But the command is not working.

Ideally I would lake to be able to save the copied text into a variable.

Comment: Have you ever tried it?

browser.keys([browser.Keys.COMMAND, "v", browser.Keys.NULL]);

Comment: I actually ended up doing this totally different with .execute and a script I ran on the website. It was too much hassle for simply verifying that the correct text was copied.

Comment: @HunsKim tried your approach `.keys([client.Keys.COMMAND, "a", client.Keys.NULL])` it doesn't work, and I can't find a simple solution on the internet. Probably will move forward with Corrinnas approach with `.execute` :(

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, try this:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "a"]) // highlight text
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "c"]) // copy text
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "v"]) // paste text
```

Comment: I needed to add browser.Keys.NULL as a third element in the array, as suggested by @Huns Kim (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796607/how-to-paste-using-the-keys-command-in-nightwatch#comment53350492_31796607).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the third NULL parameter to **all** commands, not only the last one, then it worked. Sadly, I can't find any documentation about how this exactly works.

My usecase was selecting everything on a page with an image on it (ctrl+a), copying it (ctrl+v) and then navigating to another page with a CKeditor on it. Focussing on the ckeditor and pasting (ctrl+v) the image.

```js
.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, 'a', browser.Keys.NULL])
.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, 'c', browser.Keys.NULL])
.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, 'v', browser.Keys.NULL])
```

Comment: Quoting nightwatch API documentation: "Pass client.keys.NULL to the keys function to release modifiers."

Answer (score -4):

The below command worked for me to hit ENTER KEY .

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.ENTER]);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer. It's lacking formatting and a little more explanation.